# ADO Connection conflicting with other excels (very weird issue)

Tags: excel, vba

I created quite a comprehensive End User application in VBA excel the last two months which automated the whole reporting chain based on a daily dump of data in an excel sheet.

All worked fine until the tool went live. When launching my code on a operation desk, sometime the queries on the data dump returns no results.
This only happens when the tool was not opened as a first excel instance.

So, when another excel tool is open first, my tool:
      - Returns no results
      - An another instance of my tool is opened in read-only

This happens as well on windows 2007 & 2010 and on Win XP & Windows 7.
It opens the other excel on following line (where the issue is situated:
    'adoConn.Open sConnString'

Below my code:

```
Public Function createConnection() As ADODB.Connection

Dim DbPath As String
Dim sConnString As String
Dim adoConn As New ADODB.Connection


DbPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName

'Define connection String
'http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/tutorials/article.php/c19307/Whats-in-an-ADO-Connection-String.htm
sConnString = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DbPath & ";HDR=Yes';"

'Open the connection
adoConn.Open sConnString

'Return the connection
Set createConnection = adoConn

End Function
```

Comment: I haven't heard of this affecting the results returned (unless perhaps your code is also loading the data into the workbook, or the workbook hasn't been saved) but the read-only copy is a longstanding bug. It's generally not recommended to use ADO to connect to an open workbook.

Comment: Hey Rory, I didn't know about this bug. This kinda s*cks. What's the most easy to use alternative. Thanks

Comment: Close the data source if at all possible - even if it means saving a copy of the workbook.

Comment: Comments below comes to the same solution. It seems I will have to rewrite my tool a bit. Hope it works..

Comment: Indeed it works with my datadump in an external sheet. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The connection string you're using isn't the standard Excel connection string for ADO. Replace:

```
sConnString = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DbPath & ";HDR=Yes';"

adoConn.Open sConnString
```

with the following:

```
With adoConn
   .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
   .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & dbPath & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
   .Open
End With
```

I rarely have issues with querying open workbooks with ADO (apart from occasional phantom read-only copies appearing)

Comment: I replaced the code but the issue still remains. You talk about 'occasional phantom read-only copies appearing', is this a known bug? Thanks!

Comment: I've occasionally ended up with read-only second copies of the workbook I'm querying through ADO. This doesn't happen very often though and I can normally query open workbooks with no issues. There is an ancient KB article about memory leaks caused by querying open workbooks [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319998) but no indication that it's still a current issue. Is it one specific other Excel tool which is causing this problem or is it just the fact of having another Excel instance open first that causes this?

Comment: It's occurs when I did not open my tool first. So with any other random   excel. From Microsoft: "If possible, query the Excel worksheet only while the file is not open in Excel." So if I understand correctly, I have to export my data to an external sheet and make the ADO connection to that external sheet where after I close the external excel sheet. As of then I should be able to query without memory problems...??

Comment: Yes - all of the advice I've seen suggests querying a closed workbook to avoid these kind of issues.

Comment: I managed to locate my data dump into an external excel sheet and now it doesn't seem to bug anymore. Will have to rewrite some more code and some more testing but all look good. Thanks for the help.